# How to programmatically switch to a specific window in compiz?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, x11, window-managers

Is there a command to tell compiz that we want to bring in front and set focus to a specific window?
How should we identify the window in that command?

The **reason** behind this question is the following use-case:

Suppose we have a wiki to keep notes of anything interesting we find out. It would be very convenient to have a keyboard shortcut to bring the browser window with our Wiki page in front and start typing immediately then with another key combination switch to the application we were working before

I know that <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> switches between the last two used windows but cannot support more complex combinations of applications. E.g Browser+Eclipse+ Wiki

If there is a command like the one described, it is easy to add a shortcut to it from KDE or GNOME interface

Comment: Could you add the tag [window-managers] to this question.  Thx.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you are looking for is **wmctrl**.
For example, add a keyboard shortcut to invoke a command like

```
wmctrl -Fa 'Wiki - Google Chrome'
```

to raise and activate the window with that title.

There are different ways of selecting a window by title, id, etc. See **man wmctrl**.
The list of windows can be obtained running

```
$ wmctrl -l
```

I haven't tried it with compiz but **wmctrl** should work for any EWMH compliant window manager.

Comment: Just a sidenote: wmctrl's -F option makes it look for exact match on window title. Otherwise, its just substring search (which may be better suited for some purposes).

Comment: Yep, one may use `wmctrl -a 'Google Chrome'` to switch to the first window partially matching that string.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me with Compiz:

```
xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class firefox`
```

Comment: Worked for me just now under Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity, whereas wmctrl did not.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need two separate xdotool commands; you can use %1 to refer to the first search result, or %@ to refer to all of them:  xdotool search --onlyvisible --class firefox windowactivate %@

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to send the `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` client message to the root window. This will alert any compliant window manager (including Compiz) that you are requesting to make active a particular window.

See the [EWMH spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html), specifically the [section on `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2550738).

Note that depending on the window manager's configuration, it may refuse to honor your request, or give the user the chance to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this web page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-bring-up-application-window-to-front-from-shell-script.-83545/) that has an example source program you could compile that will take bring an X window to the front.

The key is the X11 function `XRaiseWindow`.

I imagine it would be pretty easy to write a small program and either write a wrapper script or just make the program itself robust, and then set Compiz to attach this to a global keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The Widget plugin could do what you describe.

- Configure the Widget plugin to mark the desired windows as widgets (e.g. by matching on window title or role).
- Configure the Window Rules plugin to make widget windows present on all workspaces (sticky) and to skip the taskbar.

See http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Widget